# Fixed background in mailchimp template not working

Tags: html, email, templates, mailchimp

The fixed background element is not rendering in mailchimp but works perfectly just in browser. I imported the code to create the template. Is this a mailchimp issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to try [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm) by Campaign Monitor.